# Have the Mandalorians ever fought the Sith?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, sith

The Mandalorian warriors are one of the few non-Force-sensitive entities with the prestige of ever emerging victorious against Force users, namely the Jedi Order, in a formal battle. The successful storming of the Jedi Temple and the seizure of the Darksaber as a trophy is their crowning glory. They pride themselves in this and thus do not fear nor submit to the Jedi like others do, seeing themselves as superior.

The Sith are a different beast altogether but are Force-users all the same. Given the Mandalorian warrior culture their history of victories against trained Force users, it seems unlikely that they would not see the Sith as fair game. They might in fact perceive them as the greater challenge and thus an even greater glory to triumph over in battle.

So, have the Mandalorians ever fought with the pre-Banite Sith at any point in history, back when they were more numerous and organised as an Order? If yes, how did they fare? Any notable successes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the Mandalorian Wars of 3964 BBY. However, raids began as early as 3976 BBY. The Mandalorian Wars were a series of conflicts, similar to the Clone Wars, between Mandalore, and the Sith Lords, Darths Revan and Malak, in Mandalorian territory, and beyond.

In summary, Mandalore was embroiled in a series of raids, after their leader was slain by the Sith Lords Exar Kun, and Ulic Qel-Droma. After two decades of chaos, the new leader Mandalore the Ultimate brought the conflict to its peak.
Eventually, the Sith and Meetra Surik, a.k.a the Jedi Exile, a rebel Jedi Knight, who got involved in the conflict, were captured, and sent to the Jedi Council for judgment.

Comment: Revan and Malak were not Sith at the time of the Mandalorian Wars; they may not have been especially popular with the Council, but they were not yet exiles when they left. It was only afterwards, when they pursued the Mandalorians into their own space, that they encountered the Sith Emperor and fell to the Dark Side.

Comment: For what it's worth, when the Sith returned, there was a Mandalorian civil war (the Crusaders' Schism) between the majority who favored siding with the Empire, and a group of clans under Ordo and Cadera who favored allying with the Republic. It's not mentioned whether any Sith fought in those battles or how they fared, though.